# How to make product views display also show up for Anonymous users in Drupal Commerce?

Tags: 7, views, commerce

I created a Product listing view with Add to Cart Buttons. The view displays perfectly for the Super User, but it is not displaying for Anonymous or Authenticated users.I do have a relationship "referenced product" but it is still not working for anonymous users.

What I did to solve the problem is to go to the permissions page and give everybody the "view all products" permission. This works. BUT: It might open up a security issue. Please let me know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: give view all products permission to all user but  set permission for checkout  also check https://www.drupal.org/node/1276450 there is patch for it

Comment: I already did that but on permission page there is also a Warning: Give to trusted roles only; this permission has security implications.

Comment: check drupal.org/node/1276450

Comment: it is the best solution by permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by what's written in some of the comments to issue nr 1276450, such as in [comment nr 158 of it](https://www.drupal.org/node/1276450#comment-4994174):

> **edit your View**: > "Advanced" > "Query settings" : check "Disable Query Rewriting"

[image]

For sure worth trying to see if it helps in your case. If it does, it'll be way better then the permission you granted as described in your question I think.